# Global Mouse Hook/Respond to Events in VB.Net 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, mouseevent, mouse-hook

Looking for source code example(s) of global mouse hooks compatible with VB.Net 2012.

App requirement is basic: Intercept middle-click globally.

Virtually every example I have found is out of date, buggy, or generates errors that make no sense and I can't resolve in VS 2012 Pro.

This must be a tough one as I don't see this question has been asked many times for C# and VB, but haven't come across any with answers.

Thanks.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net (and C#), when you call the SetWindowsHookEx function, use hookid WH_MOUSE_LL (=14)...  The rest is the same for delegates and the proc.